# How to give a user privileges to change system date and time?

Tags: permissions, date

I have a program which will run on Ubuntu 14.04 on an ARM device.

Everything about the program can run under standard user privileges, except they should be able to change the system date and time.

Is it possible to create a user with these extra privileges under which I can run this app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To grant a user to run a specific command with root privileges you set up a sudo rule by typing `sudo visudo` in a Terminal.

This lets you edit the `/etc/sudoers` file.

For example to grant a user Luca the privileges to run "command" as root you add the line:

> Luca ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/command

You can set the date and time by using `sudo date -s "11/20/2004 12:48:00"` [1](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/udate.htm)

Btw to synchronize time you can use ntp. To restore time and date with ntpd, use `ntpd -q -g`.

Comment: And what command would be necessary to enable changing time and date?

Comment: @ByteCommander It seems there is a date command for this.

Comment: @Luca Therefore I am asking. As it stands, the answer is incomplete and therefore by definition not a valid answer. See http://i.stack.imgur.com/vAUaw.png - If I was you, I personally would not accept it yet in its current state.

Comment: Ok i added a date (and time) example with reference...Just out of curiosity why do you need to change date and time manually? ^^ - If you messed up your time, you can use ntpd to resync time btw: "ntpd -q -g"

Comment: @Lord_PedantenStein This is an embedded device and no guarantee it will be connected to the internet. There is a setup screen with manual override option. Thanks for updating your answer!